# Python how to store string into a variable?

Tags: python

I have a python string with newlines represented like this:

```
""members" : [\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t"_id ...."
```

I want to store the string in a variable but with the \n and \t converted into newlines and tabs:

```
"members" : [
                {
                        "_id" .... "
```

The reason is because I'm using it in a command that I'm formatting and if I use .format(string) then it formats the command with the \n instead of the actual new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a string literal, \t and \n normally *are* replaced the the tab and newline characters.  To see that, however, you need to print the string as it is, not its representation.  Interactive echo prints the representation.

```
>>> s = 'a\tb\nc'
>>> s
'a\tb\nc'
>>> print(s)
a   b
c
>>> print(repr(s))
'a\tb\nc'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like that

```
stringVariable="""
                  Text1
                  text2
                  text3"""
```